# Find the name and Job of the emps who earn Max salary and Commission in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

please help me with the following query in sqlite;

Find the name and Job of the emps who earn Max salary and Commission.

```
select * from emp where sal = (select max(sal) from emp) and comm. is
not null;
```

**it does not give me the data which includes the not null values of the comm**.it just gives me the field with the highest salary but no comm value.

I have the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
EMPNO    INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY
                      NOT NULL,
ENAME    VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
JOB      VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
MGR      INTEGER (20),
HIREDATE DATE         NOT NULL,
SAL      INTEGER      NOT NULL,
COMM     INTEGER,
DEPTNO   INTEGER      REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO) 
);
```

as u can see the comm is not constrained to not null.

thank a lot in advance! :)))

Comment: Sample data (As insert statements to go along with your table definition), and expected results would be nice.

Comment: Presumably (since it causes a syntax error), the `.` in `and comm. is` is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the highest salary of all employees *who also have some (i.e not `null`) commission*, then your original query (with extra `.` removed):

```
select * from emp where sal = (select max(sal) from emp) and comm is not null;
```

is doing the wrong thing. The inner `select` finds the highest salary of *all* employees (whether or not they also have commission) and then selects all records matching that salary which *do* have some commission. With the following test data:

```
insert into emp (ename,job,hiredate,sal,comm) values
       ('a','a','a',100,null),
       ('b','b','b',200,22),
       ('c','c','c',300,33),
       ('d','d','d',400,null) ;
```

the inner `select` will return `400` (the highest of *all* salaries) and the outer `select` will return nothing, because the only record with that salary has a `null` commission.

One might be tempted to move the `and comm is not null` clause into the first `select` statement:

```
select * from emp where sal = (select max(sal) from emp where comm is not null) ;
```

and this will return `3|a|a||a|300|33|` – the highest salary of all employees with *some* commission. However, this is probably not what is wanted. Should we add another employee on the highest salary and non-null commission:

```
insert into emp (ename,job,hiredate,sal,comm) values ('x','x','x',400,44);
```

then it will return *both* records with that salary:

```
4|d|d||d|400||
5|x|x||x|400|44|
```

We *could* restore the `comm is not null` test to the outer `select` (so it occurs twice), but there is a better way:

```
select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, max(sal), comm, deptno from emp where comm is not null ;
```

which will return just the one record (with the *original* test data):

```
3|c|c||c|300|33|
```

and one with the augmented test data:

```
5|x|x||x|400|44|
```

(I have chosen to list the fields explicitly, as this is usually considered better than using `*`. However, `select *, max(sal) ...` would also produce a similar effect, although it would duplicate the `sal` field).

In many (most?) SQL dialects, you cannot mix aggregate functions (e.g. `MAX`) with non-aggregated values. However, SQLite does permit this, and – where `MIN` or `MAX` is used – guarantees that any non-aggregate values will come from the same row. From [Side note: Bare columns in an aggregate queries](https://sqlite.com/lang_select.html#bareagg) in SQLite's documentation:

> Special processing occurs when the aggregate function is either min() or max(). Example:
>
> `SELECT a, b, max(c) FROM tab1 GROUP BY a;`
>
> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query, all bare columns in the result set take values from the input row which also contains the minimum or maximum. So in the query above, the value of the "b" column in the output will be the value of the "b" column in the input row that has the largest "c" value. There is still an ambiguity if two or more of the input rows have the same minimum or maximum value or if the query contains more than one min() and/or max() aggregate function. Only the built-in min() and max() functions work this way.

(The ambiguity is in *which* of the rows the non-aggregate values are taken; I am virtually certain that elsewhere it is stated that they will all come from the *same* row).